# Javascript If false return behaving in unexpected way. Why?

Tags: javascript

The following code displays two alert messages as one would expect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("js code starting");

    alert("js code ending");
</script>
```

But for some reason I fail to understand this code displays NO alert messages:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("js code starting");

    if (false) {
        return;
    }

    alert("js code ending");
</script>
```

I would fully expect this 2nd set of code to display both alert messages.  What is the reason that it displays non?

Comment: Because a `return` statement that's not inside a function is a syntax error. Open up the developer console.

Comment: Yeah, try putting the whole thing in a `$( document ).ready()` and you'll get the result you're looking for

Comment: @Pointy Post that as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your return statement isn't encapsulated inside a function so the page views this as an error and thus no alert messages display.